# XmlSerializer reuse same class with different namespace

Tags: c#, .net, rest, wcf

I made a rest service with wcf. Now I have the following problem I want to reuse multiple classes with a different namesapce. This is how I used the XmlSeralizer for the class.

```
[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.eysnap.com/mPlayer")]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Customer", Namespace = "http://www.eysnap.com/mPlayer", IsNullable = false)]
public class Customer
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

     [XmlElement]
     public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Now I tried to reuse the class with a different namespace. I found out that this solution worked, but is there a nicer way to solve the problem?

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/XML";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Customer), "myNamescpace");
var sw = new StringWriter();
serializer.Serialize(sw, new Customer("test", "test1"));
byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sw.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is "no, that's about right" The longer version is the same, but with the warning that it is important that you store and re-use this serializer instance:

- when you use `new XmlSerializer(Type)`, the dynamically generated assembly is cached and re-used between serializer instances
- but for all other `new XmlSerializer(...)` constructs, it isn't